# How to verify whether the share has write access?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having share with write access. I am writing a powershell script to write a log file in that share.

I would like to check the condition whether i am having write access to this share before writing in it.

How to check for write access/Full control using powershell?

I have tried with Get-ACL cmdlet.

```
 $Sharing= GEt-ACL "\\Myshare\foldername
    If ($Sharing.IsReadOnly) { "REadonly access" , you can't write" }
```

It has Isreadonly property, But is there any way to ensure that the user has Fullcontrol access?

Comment: Have you tried something? Show a little effort to solve your problems and community will help you.

Comment: @Christian: Buddy I have updated my efforts in the question.

Comment: You can use [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) from Sysinternals. The other option is to use the Win32 function [`GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which calls the same API that's called when you use the effective permission tab of the file/folder properties. However this is much more complicated to  implement in PowerShell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does the same thing as @Christian's C# just without compiling C#.

```
function Test-Write {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter()] [ValidateScript({[IO.Directory]::Exists($_.FullName)})]
        [IO.DirectoryInfo] $Path
    )
    try {
        $testPath = Join-Path $Path ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
        [IO.File]::Create($testPath, 1, 'DeleteOnClose') > $null
        # Or...
        <# New-Item -Path $testPath -ItemType File -ErrorAction Stop > $null #>
        return $true
    } catch {
        return $false
    } finally {
        Remove-Item $testPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
Test-Write '\\server\share'
```

I'd like to look into implementing `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` in PowerShell because that will better answer the question....

Comment: remains the fact that you are using .net classes and not just cmdlets ;)

Comment: and what about: [ValidateScript({[IO.Directory]: :Exists($_.FullName)})] [IO.DirectoryInfo] $path. ?

Comment: @Christian The reasons I'd recommend staying away from embedded C# (if possible) are: 1) It's not debuggable with the ISE/PowerGUI 2) There's no syntax highlighting/code completion 3) Has different syntax rules than PowerShell. I would only recommend embedding C# to implement a feature PowerShell can't do natively (cmdlets, .NET classes) such as [bit-shifting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377(v=vs.71).aspx) or [P/Invoking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx).

Comment: @Christian oh, that's just part of the param block, it could be replaced with `[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_.FullName})]`. Its just to make sure input is valid.

Comment: I respect your opoinion but is just point of view! Powershell is buld on .net anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I use this way to check if current user has write access to a path:

```
# add this type in powershell

add-type @"
using System;
using System.IO;

public class CheckFolderAccess {

 public static string HasAccessToWrite(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using  (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(path, "Testing.txt"), 1, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
                { }
                return "Allowed";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }

}
"@

# use it in this way:

if ([checkfolderaccess]::HasAccessToWrite( "\\server\share" ) -eq "Allowed") { ..do this stuff } else { ..do this other stuff.. }
```

Code doesn't check ACL but just if is possible to write a file in the path, if it is possible returns string 'allowed' else return the exception's message error.

Comment: Why not make it into a PowerShell function without using C#?

Comment: In my box the type is added by a custom module loaded in $profile. It's possible to add in a function with --IgnoreWarnings in case is reloaded

Comment: Was just thinking make the function in pure powershell. Nothing really in there requiring C#.

Comment: ok! misunderstood.. yes is possible but for the answer I've just copy and paste my code :)

Comment: @AndyArismendi I was hoping to see you pure powershell solution to this question, beacause I can't figure it out all alone :-)

Comment: Ok doke, added an example :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple function I built.  It returns "Read", "Write", "ReadWrite", and "" (for no access):

```
function Test-Access()
{
    param([String]$Path)
    $guid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    $d = dir $Path -ea SilentlyContinue -ev result
    if ($result.Count -eq 0){
        $access += "Read"
    }   
    Set-Content $Path\$guid -Value $null -ea SilentlyContinue -ev result
    if ($result.Count -eq 0){
        $access += "Write";
        Remove-Item -Force $Path\$guid
    }   
    $access
}
```