# Check for Access Denied on UNC Path

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I'm struggling to locate a mechanism to determine if a path truely doesn't exist or if I don't have permissions to it. For instance, if I use the "Test-Path" commandlet on a path that is valid but I don't have permissions to, the result will be $false. I would prefer to use a try / catch block to try the command and catch an unathorizedAccessException exception or a ItemNotFoundException exception and handle the responses accordingly.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably if you are using invoke command and Acces Denied is coming then you need to use `Cred-SSP` .

For example:

```
$UserName='<username>'
$securekey= ConvertTo-SecureString '<secure-key>' -AsPlainText -Force;
$credentialdetail= New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$securekey;

Invoke-Command -Credentials $credentialdetail -ComputerName '<computername>' -Authentication CredSSP -ScriptBlock { '<...>' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use this .net code to catch the exception accessing a share or local path:

add this type in powershell

```
add-type @"
using System;
using System.IO;

public class CheckFolderAccess {

 public static string HasAccessToWrite(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using  (FileStream fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(path, "Testing.txt"), 1, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
                { }
                return "Allowed";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }

}
"@
```

use it in this way:

```
> [checkfolderaccess]::HasAccessToWrite("\\server\c$\system volume information")
Access to path '\\server\c$\system volume information\Testing.txt' denied.


> [checkfolderaccess]::HasAccessToWrite("\\nonexistingserver\nonexistingpath")
Path not found.
```

Comment: Why C# when you can write this in PowerShell itself?

Comment: @ShayLevy I had this diatribe with Arismendi in this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735449/how-to-verify-whether-the-share-has-write-access/9736379#9736379 and I like the c# version just for less code to write. I'm not a powershell semantic addicted :-).

Comment: I'm OK with it, fair enough ;)

Comment: If I run the code using a local UNC path such as \\localhost\c$ I get access denied; however if I run it using a UNC path referencing a remote machine, I'm getting "Could not find a part of the path". As an example, if I browse to \\servername\c$ via Windows explorer  I get a message stating access denied and asking for a valid username and password. If I use that same UNC path with the code you provided, I get the "Could not find a part of the path" returned.

Comment: In doing some additional testing, if I test using a remote machine and an actual share with everyone set to read only, the code above returns access denied as intended. Is there something unique about referencing c$ remotely when using the filestream class?